# Confusion on Memory Layout vs Memory Management Schemes

Tags: memory

I was studying some operating system concepts, got a bit confused, and now have the following question...

Does the memory layout of a program in execution (ie. text, data, stack, heap) only make sense in context of it's virtual address space? If a program is organized ("laid" out) into these logical sections in it's virtual address space, don't these sections just get messed up as soon as addresses start getting converted from virtual to physical addresses using a memory management scheme like paging or segmentation?

As far as I'm aware, these two schemes allow for non-contiguous partitioning in the physical address space. So if my "text" section was from address 0 to 100 (random size I picked) in the virtual address space, and I choose to use paging, and my page sizes were 20 addresses in length each (ie there would be 5 pages for the text section), once these pages get placed in the physical address space non-contiguously (based on wherever free space is available), wouldn't the notion of a TEXT "section" kinda not make sense anymore (as it's been chunked and scattered)?

Lastly, are the variable-sized segments in segmentation that end up in the physical address space the exact same size as the logical categories (text, data, stack, heap) of the memory layout present in the virtual space? Is the only caveat here that in the physical space the segments are scattered non-contiguously (are not adjacent to one another) but still exist wholesomely within their specific category (ie all the "data" remains together/contiguous in the physical space)?

Any help and clarification is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the memory layout of a program in execution (ie. text, data, stack, heap) only make sense in context of it's virtual address space? If a program is organized ("laid" out) into these logical sections in it's virtual address space, don't these sections just get messed up as soon as addresses start getting converted from virtual to physical addresses using a memory management scheme like paging or segmentation?

That's correct. The sections are contiguous in virtual memory, but not contiguous in physical memory. This isn't an issue since the operating system maintains page tables; the processor's MMU uses those to translate virtual to physical addresses transparently on each access, and the operating system itself can use them to figure out which (scattered) physical pages to interact with e.g. when the process ends and its memory is to be reclaimed.

> As far as I'm aware, these two schemes allow for non-contiguous partitioning in the physical address space. So if my "text" section was from address 0 to 100 (random size I picked) in the virtual address space, and I choose to use paging, and my page sizes were 20 addresses in length each (ie there would be 5 pages for the text section), once these pages get placed in the physical address space non-contiguously (based on wherever free space is available), wouldn't the notion of a TEXT "section" kinda not make sense anymore (as it's been chunked and scattered)?

The idea of  a section is still applicable in contexts where virtual addresses are applicable. Your user-mode program deals with virtual addresses (i.e. pointers essentially are virtual addresses), and a lot of the operating system still deals with virtual addresses as well. The translation to scattered physical addresses done on-demand by the MMU, and only a subset of kernel code needs to deal with physical addresses.

An aside: Those aren't realistic sizes due to the overhead of bookkeeping for pages; a typical page size is 4096 bytes, and there are ways of creating [larger pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt) on some platforms to reduce this overhead further.

> Lastly, are the variable-sized segments in segmentation that end up in the physical address space the exact same size as the logical categories (text, data, stack, heap) of the memory layout present in the virtual space? Is the only caveat here that in the physical space the segments are scattered non-contiguously (are not adjacent to one another) but still exist wholesomely within their specific category (ie all the "data" remains together/contiguous in the physical space)?

Nope, they are scattered on a page-by-page basis and not every virtual page will be backed with a physical page of memory. An example of this is e.g. due to [demand paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging) where a page only gets a physical backing lazily when one is actually needed. Pages of .text that haven't been used yet might not be loaded from disk until a pagefault actually induces the kernel to load them from disk.

Likewise if physical memory is scarce, unused pages might be evicted from virtual memory and be placed onto disk; when they're next accessed a pagefault will induce the kernel to load them back in from disk.

A virtual address might also map to a physical address that doesn't represent a physical page of DRAM memory on a DIMM somewhere. It's possible to map virtual addresses to physical addresses that represent [memory-mapped IO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O), or a page of virtual memory might be shared between two processes as a form of [cooperative communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory).

There are further tricks done for the sake of optimization. For example, Linux's `fork` syscall doesn't copy pages; rather it sets up the page tables to enable a feature called [copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write#In_virtual_memory_management), where pages are only copied when either the parent or child writes to them, and pages which are only read are shared between the two.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers. One question, perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but is your answer to part 3 still talking about Paging or Segmentation? I switched gears to talking about segmentation for that part, perhaps I didn't make it clear.

Comment: @4Matt I'm talking about paging throughout.